# asp.net via kerberos integrated windows authentication to sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows-authentication, kerberos, integrated-security

Please, can someone PLEASE give a simple, straight-forward way to enable ASP.NET > Kerberos > Sql Server?

We have clientMachine > webServer > databaseServer. The client is insistent that the site must pull the windows login and not prompt, hence the need for Kerberos and Integrated Authentication. It also MUST impersonate the user onto the db server, inducing a double-hop.

Our domain is a Windows 2003 domain, which as far as I can tell online, means Kerberos is enabled. And on a domain-joined computer,when logged in, kerbtray shows me I have a slew of tickets, so it is apparently working.

The web and database server computer accounts in AD are both "trusted for delegation".
The AD user accounts which must access the system are both "trusted for delegation".
When it is all working, I will add more users, for now two is it.

The Sql Server instance is running under LocalSystem on the database server, which as near as i can tell online, means it does NOT require messing with those SPN things at all.

Yet, when i try to log in with either user, i get

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

indicating a double-hop failure. This is furthered by the fact that in the application log on the db server there are a slew of entries from "MSSQL" saying the same thing.

I really can't believe how hard this is... i mean, IIS, SQL and Windows are all Microsoft, can't they talk better???

So in summary, i have

- a kerberos domain,

  db and web server both trusted for delegation

  users trusted for delegation

  users in a AD group

  AD group as a login in sql (and user in db)

  IIS with Anonymous off, Integrated on, Basic and Digest off

  IE with Enable Integrated on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer ultimately DID lie in the SPNs.

This system was set up on our test site, which is test.ourcompany.com, so i needed to add a new SPN for that reference. So in addition to the following:

```
HTTP/server 
HTTP/server.ourdomain.com
```

I also needed to add an additional one for:

```
HTTP/test.ourcompany.com
```

Geez, what a battle! At least it's over!  :)
Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Ultimately, what led me to the solution, was installing wireshark on the PDC, and watching for traffic on port 88 (the Kerberos port), which then showed that it did not recognize the entity being called, which showed the web name... test.ourcompany.com. That then hinted me to add an additional SPN for that, and voila! Thanks all for your help getting there!

Comment: Oy! I spoke too soon; it was only working for ONE user, other users it's not working for. BUT - other projects to move on to, ... will have to come back to this.

Comment: Actually, now it IS working for all our test users. Apparently it just took a VERY long time for the changes in AD to 'propogate' or whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 7):

Download the [Troubleshooting Kerberos Delegation](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Troubleshooting-Kerberos-72837743). Its a life saver.
At page 17 you'll find the **Active Directory Checklist**. Follow the checklist step by step.
At page 30 you'll find the **Client Application Checklist**. Verify the checklist step by step.
At page 35 is the **Middle Tier Checklist**. Verify it step by step.
At page 48 is the **Back End Checklist**. Verify it step by step.

If you still have problems, the document contains a detailed list of troubleshooting tools (kerbtray, klist, ldifde etc), detailed explanation on how to enable logging and auditing of authentication errors in the system event log, detailed explanation of all error codes in the event log entries from the authentication audit and so on and so forth.

Once you figure out *what* is wrong, it will be much easier to fix.

Comment: The download link does not exist anymore. There can I get this file now?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing should work without issue.

Your connection string should look like:

```
<add name="IntegratedAuthConnectionString" connectionString=
 "Data Source=DATABASEINSTANCE;Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Your web.config should also specify windows authentication

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Create a test page which dumps everything from the Request.ServerVariables collection and ensure that you are seeing the authenticated username and domain. Something along the lines of the code below

```
foreach (string s in Request.ServerVariables)
{
    Response.Write(s + ": " + Request.ServerVariables[s] + "<br />");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. My connection string is actually built dynamically by some code. I dumped it for debugging, and it is such: 
`"Data Source=DBSERVER\SQLEXPRESS05;Initial Catalog=myDb;Integrated Security=True".`